# Navigation stack state status

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
Just a quick question about the navigation stack, can I see the current machine state in the topic monitor ? I have seen the status of the goal but not the current state machine status.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221503/navigation-stack-state-status/) by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2015-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can visualize everything in rviz, obviously if you monitor the corresponding topics in any other environment you would be able to read them. Here is the guide about how to setup rviz for the navigation stack: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Using%20rviz%20with%20the%20Navigation%20Stack

hope it helps
Mohsen

---

Originally posted by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) with karma: 397 on 2015-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2015-12-16**:
Thanks for your reply, but I would like to see just the state of the navigation ("goal reached","target accepted","moving",...)

**Comment by [mohsen1989m](https://answers.ros.org/users/22803/mohsen1989m/) on 2015-12-16**:
you can see weather you reached the goal like this [example](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals)

More functions could be found [here](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleActionClient.html)

**Comment by [TomSon](https://answers.ros.org/users/23335/tomson/) on 2015-12-16**:
Yeah this kind of code will be helpful for my furture application but I thought that there is dedicated gui or a plugin to display the state of goals.